# SQL - Select column and add records based on enum

Tags: sql, enums

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to set up my query.

I have a simple 2-column table matching an object id(int) to a tag(string). There's also a legacy data-type, object type(int) that I would like to convert into a tag from the query. For example:

`TAG TABLE := { ID, TAG } : (1, FOO), (1, MINT), (2, BAR), (3, FOOBAR), (5, SAUCY)`

`OBJECT TABLE := { ID, ..., TYPE } : (1, ..., 0), (2, ..., 0), (3, ..., 1),(4, ..., SAUCY)`

And the types transfer to tags in the following way (again, an example)

`[ 0 -> AWESOME ], [ 1 -> SUPER]`

So my goal is to make a query that, using this data, returns:

`RETURN TABLE := { ID, TAG_NAME } : (1, AWESOME), (1, FOO), (1, MINT), (2, AWESOME), (2, BAR), (3, FOOBAR), (3, SUPER), (4, SAUCY), (5, SAUCY)`

How would I go about setting this up? I tried using case statements for the object type but couldn't get the query to compile... I'm hoping this isn't too tough to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like a simple UNION ALL:

```
SELECT ID, TAG FROM TagTable
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, CASE 
  WHEN TYPE=0 THEN 'AWESOME'
  WHEN TYPE=1 THEN 'SUPER'
  {etc}
END AS TAG 
FROM ObjectTable
```

Although maybe you need to do some extra join to get your TypeName using the Type in the Object Table.  You don't mention where "Awesome" and "Super" come from in your database.

Comment: Well these will be statically defined names. They have names in the object table but are represented as int's instead of strings. (Legacy stuff)

Comment: So you do a CASE statement in the second half of the UNION ALL.  WHEN Type=0 THEN 'Awesome', etc.

Comment: You don't need "AS TAG" in the second operand of the UNION ALL operator. The attribute names are defined only by the first operand.

Comment: True that it isn't needed.   I just put it there for readability purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that

```
TRANSER_TABLE := {ID, Name} : (0, AWESOME), (1, SUPER)
```

you can write this:

```
select ID, TAG 
from TAG_TABLE

UNION ALL

select o.ID, t.Name 
from 
OBJECT_TABLE o
join TRANSER_TABLE t on o.TYPE = t.ID
```

Comment: Thanks for the general format, this'll be very handy! :)